# Replace ~ char from text from column at excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have tried my level best to remove ~ character, which is a part of text in one column at excel 2013 file.

can somebody help me replace this character(~) with underscore(_)?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The tilde (`~`) has a specific meaning within search and replace. It is the escape character to escape other characters with specific meanings like `*` and `?` which are wildcards in search. With `~*` you will find an asterisk. With `~?` you will find a question mark. So you have to use `~~` in search to find the tilde sign itself.

Comment: thanks axel richter, but its not searching the way its said in answer, my text in column looks like PO$~$2$~$PO/00469/2015$~$1, can you please look into it.

Comment: Works for me with your data. On the Home tab, click Find & Select, Replace. In Find what: enter `~~`. In Replace with: enter `_`. Now click `Replace all`.

Comment: i did the same, it ended up saying, it can not find the specified char.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-718fe326-7fd2-48e0-96e2-8de3ab465a33 Click `Options` and make sure that there the `Match entire cell contents` check box is *not* set.